# Can two nodes in a Markov chain have transitions that don't total 1?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

In all the Markov diagrams I see, the transitions from state `A` to `B` always total to one.

Just one of many examples, this image from [this](http://guizzetti.ca/blog/2012/04/markov-models-or-the-future-is-now/) website.

[image: Markov Chain]

I've also seen examples that don't have values, but have variables. 
For example this diagram:

[image: Markov Diagram]

What I'm wondering is: **if $P_{AB}$ is the only path from $A$ to $B$, does $P_{AB}$ have to be $1$?**

Comment: Looks to me like the transition from A to B is only 0.8.  What does have to add up to 1 is all the paths FROM A. It has to go somewhere, even if just back to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition probabilities from one node to the other nodes have to sum up to $1$. This is true even if there is only one path out of a certain state.

In what follows let $A^n$ the $n^{th}$ state and let $A_{i}^{n+1}$ denote the $(n+1)^{st}$ state of the Markov chain. Also, suppose that $P(A^n)>0$. $(i=1,2, ... m)$ Then
$$\sum_{1} ^{m}P(A_{i}^{n+1}|A^n)=\sum_{1} ^{m}\frac{P(A_{i}^{n+1}\cap A^n)}{P(A^n)}=\frac{1}{P(A^n)}\sum_{1} ^{m}P(A_{i}^{n+1}\cap A^n)=\frac{P(A^n)}{P(A^n)}=1.$$